# Most related texts/items based on common tags algorithm in Scala

Tags: algorithm, scala, tags

I have 50M different texts as input from which the top (up to) 10 most relevant tags have been extracted.

There are ~100K distinct tags

I would like to develop an algorithm that, given a text id T1 as input (present in the original input data set), computes the most related text id T2 based on the fact that T2 is the text that have most tags in common with T1.

```
id | tags
-------------
 1 | A,B,C,D
 2 | B,D,E,F
 3 | A,B,D,E
 4 | B,C,E
```

In the example above, the most similar id to 1 is 3 as they have 3 tags in common

This seems to be the same algorithm that shows the most related questions in StackOverflow.

My first idea was to map both texts and tags to integers to build a big (50M * 100K) binary matrix that is very sparse.

This matrix fits in memory, but I do not know how to use it.

As this is for a web application, I would like to deliver the result in real time conditions (at most a few ms, with possible multi-threading).

My main languages are Scala and Java.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Not sure how close this to the task you are trying to solve, but I would start from this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a very interesting article, how ever, as the tags have benen already extracted, I only have the text id and the list of tags associated with it as input.